# Keep fullscreen mode when navigating through webApp in iOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, fullscreen

I do have a web app which opens in fullscreen mode when launched from iOS homescreen via icon using the meta tag

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

I also want to keep fullscreen mode when navigating through my app using normal

```
<a href="category/pageA.html">Page A</a>
```

links. I found several solution approaches setting the `location.href` manually to prevent iOS open the new page in Safari browser but this does not seems to work.

My current (non working) approach is as follows:

```
var openLink = function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let target = event.target;
  while (target.tagName.toUpperCase() !== 'A') {
    target = target.parentNode;
  }
  let href = target.href;
  window.location.href = href;
  return false;
};
```

And then on each (internal) link use

```
<a href="category/pageA.html" onclick="openLink()">Page A</a>
```

But this does not work and when clicked still opens Safari showing the linked page in normal mode (no fullscreen and with addressbar).

The only thing I currently did not try is to refactor my Web App to be a Single Page Application and thus don't have "real" links inside it. But if possible I would like to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but try replacing

```
window.location.href = href;
```

with

```
window.location.assign( href );
```

or

```
window.location.replace( href );
```

The former allows navigation via `window.history.back()`, the latter doesn't.